# Linear Algebra: Question about determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

The following matrices are $4 \times 4$ matrices.

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1& 1 &0\\
1 &1 &0 &0 \end{bmatrix}\\
B= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1& 1& 1 \\ 1 & 1& 1& 1 \\ 1& 1& 1& 0 \\1 & 1& 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \\
C= \begin{bmatrix} x & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1&1&1&0 \\1&1&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

1. Find $\det{A}$
2. Find the cofactor $C_{11}$ of $B$ and then use that to find $\det{B}$
3. Use the above results to find $\det{C}$ in terms of $A$ and $B$

I know the solutions, but I would like an explanation why.

> $\det{A}=0$, $\det{B}=1$, $\det{C}= -(x-1)\det{B}$.

Comment: The first two rows of $A$ are the same. What does this tell you about the determinant of $A$?

Comment: Hi, Sachet. You might find the following MathJax tutorial helpful when writing your next question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: the explanation is rather easy. I can answer your question and explain the solution for you. But please provide additional information about your efforts on the problem. This way the other users will understand your level of knowledge about determinants and so will give you better explaination

Answer (score 1):

we know that **aading the coefficient of one row to the other does not change the determinant** so for matrix $A$ we can subtract the second row from the first row

$$\det A=\begin{vmatrix}1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&0\\
1&1&0&0\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}1&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&0\\
1&1&0&0\end{vmatrix}=0$$
From the fact that if all of the elements in a column or row is zero, the determinant will be zero
For matrix $B$, we first subtract second row from the first row in order to make the determinant simpler and to have just one nonzero element in the first row (This way the expansion of determinant w.r.t the first row will be much easier) so:
$$\det B=\begin{vmatrix}0&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&0\\
1&1&0&0\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}-1&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&0\\
1&1&0&0\end{vmatrix}=(-1)\underbrace{(-1)^{1+1}\begin{vmatrix}1&1&1\\
1&1&0\\
1&0&0\end{vmatrix}}_{C_{11}\text{cofactor of B}}=(-1)(1)(-1)^{1+3}\begin{vmatrix}1&1\\
1&0\end{vmatrix}=(-1)(-1)=1$$
For $C$ we have:
$$\det C=\begin{vmatrix}x&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&0\\
1&1&0&1\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}x-1&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&0\\
1&1&0&1\end{vmatrix}=(x-1)(-1)^{1+1}\begin{vmatrix}1&1&1\\
1&1&0\\
1&0&1\end{vmatrix}$$
From the previous calculation we know that:
$$(-1)(-1)^{1+1}\begin{vmatrix}1&1&1\\
1&1&0\\
1&0&0\end{vmatrix}=\det B\Rightarrow (-1)^{1+1}\begin{vmatrix}1&1&1\\
1&1&0\\
1&0&0\end{vmatrix}=-\det B$$
So:
$$\det C=(x-1)(-1)^{1+1}\begin{vmatrix}1&1&1\\
1&1&0\\
1&0&1\end{vmatrix}=-(x-1)\det B$$